# How to get the data written to TextIOWrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, buffer

I first write some binary data to a `TextIOWrapper` object.

Then need to get the result of all writes concatenated (in the example below it would be `b"XXXYYY"`). How to get the result of writes?

```
import sys
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

file = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)

file.buffer.write(b"XXX")
file.buffer.write(b"YYY")

print(file) # does not work
```

Comment: `file.buffer.getvalue()` seems to work. But the docs say that `buffer` is not a part of public API

Comment: But why you need `TextIOWrapper` instead of pure `BytesIO`?

Comment: @Sraw I replace (monkey-patch) sys.stdout with my `TextIOWrapper` object (for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to catch `stdout`. Actually it is easy:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO


f = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    print("Hello", end="")
s = f.getvalue()
print("s: ", s)
```

As you can see, you don't need a `TextIOWrapper`.

Comment: With your approach `sys.stdout.buffer.write("Hello")` does not work, but I need to redirect namely `sys.stdout.buffer`.